# Cloudera Navigator API fail to fetch nested data

Tags: java, bigdata, cloudera-navigator

I am working in Cloudera Manager Navigator REST API where extracting result is working fine, but unable to get any nested value.

The type of data is extracting as below.

```
{
    "parentPath": "String",
    "customProperties": "Map[string,string]",
    "sourceType": "String",
    "entityType": "String"
}
```

And data should be like

```
{
    "parentPath": "abcd",
    "customProperties": {
                            "nameservice" : "xyz"
                        },
    "sourceType": "rcs",
    "entityType": "ufo"
}
```

But I am getting key-value result as follows.

```
parentPath :abcd
customProperties : null
sourceType : rcs
entityType : ufo
```

In above response data, "customProperties" is coming with a null value where it should return a map object contains `["nameservice" : "xyz"]`. This is the problem with following code snippet.

```
MetadataResultSet metadataResultSet = extractor.extractMetadata(null, null,"sourceType:HDFS", "identity:*");
Iterator<Map<String, Object>> entitiesIt = metadataResultSet.getEntities().iterator(); 
     while(entitiesIt.hasNext()){
        Map<String, Object> result = entitiesIt.next();
        for(String data : result.keySet()){
                        System.out.println(" key:"+data+" value:"+result.get(data));
                        }
        }
```

Can you suggest me how to get the nested value where datatype is complex.

Answer (score 0):

have u checked how the data looks on navigator ui? You can first verify that once, and also try cloudera /entities/entity-id rest API in browser to check how json response is coming

Comment: Navigator UI doesn't contain all those details data and  "https://abcd:7777/api/v9/actions/running" is returning []. But JSON response against (/entities/entity-id) is coming with proper data. I also don't have any problem in my java code during extraction of simple data, only complex type("customProperties" as mentioned above) is returning null values.